# Call c# function from html <a>

Tags: c#, html, server-side, visual-web-developer

I'm trying to call a c# server-side function when a link is pressed.
the function is:

```
public void check()
{
    Response.Write("Clicked");
}
```

What should the a tag look like so when I press it the function will be called?

Comment: Just use a `LinkButton` and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a LinkButton in your .Aspx file:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnSumb" runat="server" Text="sgas" OnClick="btnSumb_Click" />
```

And in your code behind .Aspx.cs file:

```
protected void btnSumb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     check();
}
```

Comment: Why wont it work when I create the html in the c# code like this  - <tr><td height='30'><form runat='server' action='' method='post'><asp:LinkButton ID='LinkButton1' runat='server' OnClick='LinkButton1_Click'>" + allMovies.Rows[i][0] + "</asp:LinkButton></form></td>

Comment: It won't work like that. You have to create LinkButton dynamically from code behind like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29827063/how-to-add-dynamic-textbox-in-the-place-of-html-input/29829680#29829680

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using anchor tag use link button

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

and then you can generate click event and call your method in it.
Code in aspx.cs file

```
  protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    check();
}
public void check()
{
    Response.Write("Clicked");
}
```

Comment: Where can i call my function?